# Flip Date in the php output from sql

Tags: php, html, sql, date, output

when I grab the date from my database displaying as 2017-10-31, how do I display it as 31-10-2017 when outputting using php?

At the moment it just displays the Date as formatted by the database.

```
    $Date = $row['Date'];
<body>
     <?php echo $Date; ?>
</body>
```

How can you flip the date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it by using following methods
**By Mysql DATE_FORMAT::**

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%d-%m-%Y")`.

**By PHP `date`::**

```
$timestamp = $row['Date'];
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($timestamp));
```

**By PHP `DateTime`::**

```
$objDT = new DateTime($row['Date']);
echo $objDT->format('d-m-Y');
```

**By PHP `date_format`::**

```
$dt_row=date_create($row['Date']);
echo date_format($dt_row,"d-m-Y");
```

> these methods are used by your need accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Either MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) (or MSSQL's [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) if that's your bag), or php's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use date converter

```
$date = $row['Date'];
<body>
     <?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date)); ?>
</body>
```

Without strtotime method

```
$date = $row['Date'];
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
<body>
    <?php echo $date1->format('d-m-Y'); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: stop using the legacy `strtotime` you should always use the DateTime class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions date() and strtotime():

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($Date));
```

Comment: stop using the legacy `strtotime` you should always use the DateTime class